# Solr eDisMax query

Tags: solr, edismax

I have field "spell" with text "Quanti disperati si rovescerebbero con i barconi sulle nostre.."

I can search via edismax like this one:

```
q={!field f=spell}disperati si rovescerebbero' - OK
```

or

```
q={!prefix f=spell}disperat' - OK
```

but how can I search not a complete sentence something like this one:

```
q={!field f=spell}disperati si rovescere*' - INCORRECT
```

Comment: whats the f parameter ? should it be qf ? Try - q={!type=dismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescere*'}

Comment: No it dosn`t work. q={!type=dismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescere*'} - return nothing but if I search like this one q={!type=dismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescerebbero'} - it returns data, but I need to search by not complete phrase like "disperati si rovescerebbe" or "disperati si rove".

Comment: q={!type=edismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescerebbero'} returns the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
q={!type=edismax qf=spell v='disperati si rovescerebbero*'}
```